# Webpack style-loader insert SCSS into shadow-dom

Tags: reactjs, webpack, shadow-dom, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to configure webpack to insert my custom SCSS styles into a shadow DOM node instead of at the head of the document. The location of the shadow DOM node will not always be consistent, so the ability to pass an element to insert the styles into dynamically is key.

The [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#insert) references a function that can be used in `style-loader` configuration called `insert` that allows a function to be created in order to specify where the styles are to be added. Importing the styles and calling the `use` function with a `target` parameter is how the example specifies the other element for the styles to be added to.

The issue I am having is the second parameter called `options` in the insert function is always undefined. The `element` argument is present and contains the correct custom styles tag contents, but the `options` object that specifies where to add these styles to is never defined so the styles end up getting added to the document head which is not the desired outcome.

Here is my relevant webpack code:

```
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            exclude: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /\.lazy\.scss$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.lazy\.scss$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: {
                        injectType: 'lazyStyleTag',
                        insert: function insertIntoTarget(element, options) {
                            var parent = null;
                            if (!options) {
                                parent = document.head;
                            } else {
                                parent = options.target;
                            }
                            parent.appendChild(element);
                        },
                    },
                },
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ],
        },
       ]
      }
```

Here is the relevant react code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styles from './styles/Component.lazy.scss';

const Component = () => {
    return (
        <div>Component in shadow DOM</div>
    );
};

if (document.querySelector('div.ComponentClass') === null) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'ComponentClass';
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    const shadow = document.querySelector('div.ComponentClass').attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const target = document.querySelector('div.ComponentClass').shadowRoot;

    styles.use({ target });

    ReactDOM.render(<Component />, target);
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here that is causing the `options` parameter to always be undefined?

I have also tried a few variations of passing different things into the `styles.use` functions as well, such as `{ options: { target: ... } }` and it seems that only the `element` parameter is passed in no matter what

Comment: Hi. Have you already solved this? If not can you mention what version of Webpack and react are you using. If resolved please provide comment to explain what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading your `style-loader` version? Here's the PR which added this feature:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/pull/535

Version 3.0.0 *doesn't* have it. Version 3.3.1 definitely does support passing arguments to `use`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).